# Accessing GDAL from Terminal with OS X Mavericks?

Tags: gdal, ogr

I successfully installed QGIS on my iMac with OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks using the installers provided by Kyngchaos. However, I'm having troubles accessing GDAL / ogr from terminal. It's giving me the following error message:

> -bash: ogr2ogr: command not found

Does anybody have an idea of how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

You must understand the PATH and the $PATH variable on POSIX and Unix-like operating systems (as Mac OS X, look at  [The PATH Variable](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html)) and BASH

The GDAL programs of Kyngchaos, as [Laurent Jégou](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/750/laurent-jegou) says, are installed in

/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/

[image]

so, in the terminal, use the command:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
```

[image]

If you do not want to write it every time, put this line in your .bash_profile file in /Users/you/ (hidden file, look at [Hidden file and hidden directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)):

[image]

Portion of my .bash_profile file

[image]

And each time you open Terminal.app, you automatically get the right paths:

[image]

Comment: The export PATH workaround is working for me, thank you. But I'm unable to locate the .bash_profile file on my machine. I set all files to visible and searched it with finder but no result. Is it possible that this file is called differently on Mavericks? Thanks again, Ralf

Comment: you can create one (name = .bash_profile)

Answer (score 1):

Try "locate ogr2ogr", it will give you the full path of the tool.

On my own 1.10 install, its "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/ogr2ogr"